# How to implement a voice(and later video)chat between Vr devices and an angular frontend?

Tags: angular, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, signalr, virtual-reality

Hy, I'm working on an application that connects Vr devices (unity) with angular frontends by sending data to a Asp.net Core 3.1 Api.

Well, The whole connection is working by using SignalR Core to send json objects over. But one of the new requirements is that the both clients can comunicate with each other by using voice chat (and later video). In my research I have found that SignalR is not created to make these kind of calls.

We also found that [CometChat](https://cometchat.com) is only for frontend and not for asp.net core or Vr devices. Agora sends the voice data to there own servers and then back but because it is sensible data it Must remain on our own servers (so asp.net core 3.0).

Any Idea's?

[UPDATE]

Hi, 
We have 3 applications.

1 Unity (platform WebGL)

2 Asp.net Core 3.1 WebAPI.

3 Angular(7.x.x) Frontend

The communication between 1-2 and 2-3 is made with SignalR.

In a tutorial we have implemented simple-peer into the angular project and made a connection between 3-2-3. Offcouse we want the connection now between 1-2-3 or 3-2-1.

The problem is we have no idea how to implement the WebRTC or simple-peer in Unity to make this connection (peer-to-peer).

We have bought and tried [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/webrtc-video-chat-68030) and [this unity](https://web.archive.org/web/20170730015446/http://keywordnerd.com/webrtc-unity) package but i dont know how to implement it.

please any help? we're stuck

Comment: Are the angular frontends running in the browser or is this in electron or something?

Comment: just in the browser

Answer (score 10):

Your best bet is to use a standards voice-chat plugin, like [WebRTC Video Chat](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/webrtc-video-chat-68030?aid=1100lJDF&utm_source=aff) for the Unity client.

Then, create a scene with just the plugin and embed a WebGL player right into your HTML page (what you are calling your Angular frontend). This way, you can ensure pretty rigorous compatibility and stay within the boundaries of what the plugin author has actually tested, although it's possible any WebRTC-based video conferencing will be compatible.

You can also attempt to port (or study the code of) the [Dissonance](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/dissonance-for-webrtc-network-143294) plugins to improve the quality of voice chat.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't reply. I've updated my Question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much it will help you, there is a simple stackblitz integration with webRTC.

In app.module.ts, make changes as below:

```
const config = {
 apiKey: "AIzaSyCpqI773ach6MxOcIqRvgDFBVVTvLJW-Ew",
 authDomain: "sample6-d38d3.firebaseapp.com",
 databaseURL: "https://sample6-d38d3.firebaseio.com",
 projectId: "sample6-d38d3",
 storageBucket: "gs://sample6-d38d3.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "358754973898"
};

@NgModule({
   imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
            AngularFireDatabaseModule
           ],
   declarations: [AppComponent, MeetingComponent],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

Add new component as below:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  NgZone
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  AngularFireList
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
declare
let RTCPeerConnection: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meeting',
  templateUrl: './meeting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meeting.component.css']
})
export class MeetingComponent implements OnInit {
  callActive: boolean = false;
  pc: any;
  localStream: any;
  channel: AngularFireList < {} > ;
  database: firebase.database.Reference;
  senderId: string;

  @ViewChild("me") me: any;
  @ViewChild("remote") remote: any;

  constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setupWebRtc();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pc.close();
    let tracks = this.localStream.getTracks();
    for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      tracks[i].stop();
    }
    this.callActive = false;
  }

  setupWebRtc() {
    this.senderId = this.guid();
    var channelName = "/webrtc";
    this.channel = this.afDb.list(channelName);
    this.database = this.afDb.database.ref(channelName);
    this.database.on("child_added", this.readMessage.bind(this));

    try {
      this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [{
            urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"
          },
          {
            urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        optional: []
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [{
            urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"
          },
          {
            urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        optional: []
      });
    }


    this.pc.onicecandidate = event => {
      event.candidate ? this.sendMessage(this.senderId, JSON.stringify({
        ice: event.candidate
      })) : console.log("Sent All Ice");
    }

    this.pc.onremovestream = event => {
      console.log('Stream Ended');
    }

    this.pc.ontrack = event =>
      (this.remote.nativeElement.srcObject = event.streams[0]); // use ontrack
    this.showMe();
  }

  sendMessage(senderId, data) {
    var msg = this.channel.push({
      sender: senderId,
      message: data
    });
    msg.remove();
  }

  readMessage(data) {
    if (!data) return;
    try {
      var msg = JSON.parse(data.val().message);
      let personalData = data.val().personalData;
      var sender = data.val().sender;
      if (sender != this.senderId) {
        if (msg.ice != undefined && this.pc != null) {
          this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(msg.ice));
        } else if (msg.sdp.type == "offer") {
          this.callActive = true;
          this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp))
            .then(() => this.pc.createAnswer())
            .then(answer => this.pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
            .then(() => this.sendMessage(this.senderId, JSON.stringify({
              sdp: this.pc.localDescription
            })));
        } else if (msg.sdp.type == "answer") {
          this.callActive = true;
          this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg.sdp));
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  showMe() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
      })
      .then(stream => (this.me.nativeElement.srcObject = stream))
      .then(stream => {
        this.pc.addStream(stream);
        this.localStream = stream;
      });
  }

  showRemote() {
    try {
      this.pc.createOffer()
        .then(offer => this.pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => {
          this.sendMessage(this.senderId, JSON.stringify({
            sdp: this.pc.localDescription
          }));
          this.callActive = true;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setupWebRtc();
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  hangup() {
    this.pc.close();
    let tracks = this.localStream.getTracks();
    for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      tracks[i].stop();
    }
    this.callActive = false;
  }

  guid() {
    return (this.s4() + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + "-" + this.s4() + this.s4() + this.s4());
  }
  s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <video id="device" controls autoplay #remote>
 </video>
  <video id="me" controls autoplay #me></video>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showRemote()" [disabled]="callActive">Connect</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="hangup()" [disabled]="!callActive">Disconnect</button>
```

I have added this code here in case this link got broken.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webrtc?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: well sadly it doesn't. This shows only the setup for angular but it doesn't enclude the Unity setup or the backend.

Comment: Here is a link with node js and simple html and javascript, with angular application you can easily use node js. https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-simplewebrtc/

Comment: Still. it saids nothing on the unity C# part. There is a lot of information available on the angular part alone. but not on the unity part. and the main problem is the combination of both.